# Recursive PHP function is not returning expected value

Tags: php, function, recursion, return

I am trying to create a function that will create a unique username for each user stored in the database.

My plan was to create a username by concatenating the first and last name then check if this username was taken. If it wasn't just store it in the database and if it was then add a number on the end of it.

For example if ConnorAtherton was taken the function would next check ConnorAtherton1, ConnorAtherton2 until it found a unique username.

Here is the function (I have added some echo statements for debugging)

```
    function createUserName($username, $counter){

        global $fname, $lname;

        echo "\t\t\tUsername at Start - " . $username . "\n";

        // connect to database
        require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/inc/db.connect.php");

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        echo "\t\t\tUsername before loop - " . $username . "\n";

            if( $stmt->num_rows > 0){

                //construct original name and try again
                $username = ucfirst($fname) . ucfirst($lname) . $counter;
                $counter++;
                createUserName($username, $counter);

            }

            echo "\t\t\tUsername after loop - " . $username . "\n\n";

            return $username;
    }
```

Here is what it returns to the console

```
    Username at Start - ConnorAtherton
    Username before loop - ConnorAtherton
    Username at Start - ConnorAtherton1
    Username before loop - ConnorAtherton1
    Username at Start - ConnorAtherton2
    Username before loop - ConnorAtherton2
    Username after loop - ConnorAtherton2

    Username after loop - ConnorAtherton1
```

It returns the correct value after the loop (ConnorAtherton2) to begin with but I don't know why there would be a second value after the loop.

It returns ConnorAtherton1 and I need it to return ConnorAtherton2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but I would think about changing your sql to use `WHERE username LIKE "ConnorAtherton%"`, and then substringing off the last digit(s) and adding 1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code executes as expected. What you are seeing is just the stack unwinding from the recursive calls.

You should modify your function to exit after the recursive call, by returning the result from the recursive call

```
     //...
    $counter++;
    return createUserName($username, $counter);
 }
 //... Rest of fn omitted
```

Comment: Great. I'm glad I could help! On a related note, as others have pointed out you can achieve the same without recursion but understanding recursive functions can always come in handy;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want without recursion much easier. The basic logic would look like this:

```
$counter = '';
do {
    $username = ucfirst($fname) . ucfirst($lname) . ($counter++);
} while(!doesNameExist($username));
```

You'd only have to implement the `doesNameExist()` method. There you do the DB query and return `true` if the name already exists.

The `($counter++)` part will append an empty string on first iteration (the `++` suffix increases the variable *after* the value was evaluated).

Comment: Hey Michael, I agree with you that it can be done without recursion and your solution works great. I created this programming scenario so I could better understand how recursion works :)

Comment: I see. But keep in mind that you should avoid recursive calls if possible - they are usually much more expensive than a simple loop.

Comment: @Michael - as a blanket statement I can't agree with you. It really depends on the language and the task. In this case yes, it's overkill but in other cases recursion can be really great!

Comment: @Miky: You are right. It depends on wether it's a linear or iterative recursive process. So i should rephrase my statement: In PHP i'd avoid it if there is a simpler loop based solution (which is the case here). But then again, what is "simpler" ;)